# How do most android applications retrieve data from a database server?

Tags: android, ajax, rest, azure-mobile-services

I am currently working on an application which is a small applications for businesses to list their promotions on my website. I have created this in ASP.NET and I'm using a REST-like interface for my website in the back-end. I'd like to now also introduce an android application. I've noticed there are things like windows azure mobile services out there which let you easily create and integrate data services to mobile applications. My question is should I use the same interface as my website or is there a conversion people use in the commercial space.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have any experience with windows azure mobile services but I have many experience in writing APIs for different front ends (mobile/win/web/widgets) and never heart about any conventions/conversions in commercial space.
My advice is. If you need to push data to mobile application use some service that can do it or write yours. If you are going to write push notifications service you will need server to run it.
If the application will only pull data from server or push to it than better use same REST-like interface you already have. It can to avoid code duplication and will create some data exchange standard between you front ends and back end.
Hope it will help you.